# Verify my proof: "for all odd integers $a$ and $b$, $b^2-a^2 \neq 4$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm learning math without a math professor. I need some feedback from community regarding my proof.
The book is : "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Susanna S. Epp, 5th edition.
Exercise 16 from page 226. Please verify my proof.

> Prove the following statement: "for all odd integers $a$ and $b$, $b^2-a^2 \neq 4$"

**Proof**. Let's prove by contradiction. Let say there are two integers $a$ and $b$ and $b^2-a^2 = 4$. Because $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, then $a=2n+1$ and $b=2k+1$, where $n \in Z$ and $k \in Z$. Now let's perform the following computations:

$b^2 - a^2 = (2k+1)^2 - (2n+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 - 4n^2 - 4n - 1 = 4(k^2 + k - n^2 - n) = 4(k^2 - n^2 + k - n) = 4[(k+n)(k-n)+(k-n)] = 4(k-n)(k+n+1)  $

So, in order for the expression $b^2 - a^2 = 4(k-n)(k+n+1) $ to be true, $(k-n)(k+n+1)$ must be equal to 1 or -1. Then $k-n = 1$ and $k+n+1 = 1$ or $k-n = -1$ and $k+n+1 = -1$, because both of expressions should be equal to one (or minus one), we have :

$k-n = k+n+1 \implies -n = n + 1 \implies -n-n = 1 \implies -2n = 1 \implies n = -\frac{1}{2} $, so $n$ is not an integer $\blacksquare$

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo?  $b^2-a^2=(2k+1)^2-(2n+1)^2$...you wrote $(2n-1)^2$ in error.  Your final expression for the difference is correct, so I expect it's just a typo.

Comment: You cannot assume that $k-n$ and $k+n+1$ are positive. So either $1=1\cdot 1$ or $1=-1\cdot -1$. You have forgotten the case $k-n=-1$ and $k+n+1=-1$.

Comment: Details aside, there's nothing wrong with the overall approach...though it is a bit over complicated.  Start with $b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$ and work from there and you get a similar contradiction quickly.

Comment: Up to signs, $4=1\cdot 4$ and $4=2\cdot 2$. In the first case, $b-a=1,b+a=4$, so $2b=5$, a contradiction. In the second case $b=2$, which is even - contradiction. So, as lulu said (politely), your proof is too long.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, Yes, such kind of problems can be easily solved using a computer program. I just don't want to guess, but Java Long type has a max value of $2^{63}-1$. If my program finds a contradiction until max value, is this method ok to be used in mathematics ?

Comment: Robert, I did not use a computer to conclude that $4=b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$ can only mean $b-a=1,b+a=4$ or $b-a=b+a=2$, up to signs. This is just basic arithmetic, i.e., how to factor $4$.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm merely critiquing your presentation.

> > Prove the following statement: "for all odd integers $a$ and $b$, $b^2-a^2 \neq 4$"
>
> **Proof**. Let's prove by contradiction. Let say there are two integers $a$ and $b$ and $b^2-a^2 = 4$. Because $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, then $a=2n+1$ and $b=2k+1$, where $n \in Z$ and $k \in Z$.

I suggest replacing the "[where](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4506542/21813) $n\in\mathbb Z$" with "for some $n\in\mathbb Z$" (as opposed to "for all $n\in\mathbb Z$"), so that it is *immediately* clear that you are not referring to an arbitrary $n$ (consequently, an arbitrary odd integer).

> Now let's perform the following computations:
> $b^2 - a^2 = (2k+1)^2 - (2n+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 - 4n^2 - 4n - 1 = 4(k^2 + k - n^2 - n) = 4(k^2 - n^2 + k - n) = 4[(k+n)(k-n)+(k-n)] = 4(k-n)(k+n+1)  $

> So, in order for the expression $b^2 - a^2 = 4(k-n)(k+n+1) $ to be true,

This sentence is confusing: you've already, by assumption, shown it to be true. What you mean is instead something like "Equating both expressions for $b^2-a^2,$ we have that $4(k-n)(k+n+1)=4.$"

> $(k-n)(k+n+1)$ must be equal to 1 or -1. Then $k-n = 1$ and $k+n+1 = 1$ or $k-n = -1$ and $k+n+1 = -1$, because both of expressions should be equal to one (or minus one), we have :

> $k-n = k+n+1 \implies -n = n + 1 \implies -n-n = 1 \implies -2n = 1 \implies n = -\frac{1}{2} $, so $n$ is not an integer. $\blacksquare$

This is slightly confusing. If I'm merely skimming or if your text is dense, then it is not immediately clear that you are even asserting that $k-n = k+n+1$ (the leftmost antecedent) is true; in other words, it is not immediately clear whether you have actually derived that conclusion $n=-\frac12$ or whether it is provisional on that leftmost antecedent being true. I suggest using words like "so", "thus", "therefore" and "hence" instead, and [reserving](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4387367/21813) `⟹` for when you are merely asserting a conditional/implication.

Comment: Please strive not to answer off-topic / dupe questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't think this is a duplicate question, and I'm not sure that it is off-topic to ask for a feedback on (or to critique) *proof-writing*. I'm surprised by your message.

Comment: @ryang See my comment on the question.  It is surely a dupe of many, and unfocused proof checking questions add no value to the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque I went ahead and read your comment on the question, and it sounds a lil over the top, in view of the actual tag description "Solution verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. This should not be the only tag for a question".     $\quad$   [This from under an hour ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4640514/21813), I refused to answer because it is a *literal* FAQ, so clearly neither its answer nor question adds value to the site (that page has rapidly amassed 10 votes); such pages are probably more worth your consternation.