# pulling universal quantifiers in front of a disjunction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Knowing that $$(∀xP) ∨ (∀xQ)$$ is *not* equivalent with $$∀x(P ∨ Q),$$ how can I pull the quantifiers in front of the formula simple formula $$ (∀xP) ∨ (∀xQ)$$

Or $$(∃xP) ∧ (∃xQ)$$ for that matter.

Comment: see [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conversion_to_prenex_form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributive law works here just like it would for finite conjunctions and disjunctions. By analogy with

$$
(w\land x)\lor(y\land z)=(w\lor y)\land(w\lor z)\land(x\lor y)\land(x\lor z)
$$

you get

$$
(\forall xP)\lor(\forall xQ)\Leftrightarrow\forall(x,y)(P(x)\lor Q(y))\;,
$$

and likewise

$$
(\exists xP)\land(\exists xQ)\Leftrightarrow\exists(x,y)(P(x)\land Q(y))\;.
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can change $$(\forall x P(x)) \vee (\forall x Q(x)) $$
to
$$(\forall x P(x)) \vee (\forall y Q(y)) $$ by changing the choice of dummy variable, and $\textit{then}$ move the quantifiers to the front to get

$$\forall x \forall y (P(x) \vee Q(y)) $$.

Comment: The question was about $\lor$ in the middle (but your answer is still correct if you make that change).